# Query to loop and random in SQL

Tags: sql

Please an you help me with the code by this query?.

I have two fields: **'Customer'** and **'Rate'**.

Rate values: (BT5A, BT5B, BT5BR, MT1, MT2, MT3)
Customers: 1000 customers by each Rate.

I would like to make a query that randomly returns 3 customers for each rate in the table, in order to have a sample of customers per rate.

How do I improve this code?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3
c.RUTA,c.CONTRATO,c.CODIGOANT,c.CODRUTA,c.NOMBRES,c.DIRECCION,
c.SITUACION,c.TARIFA
FROM CLIENTE AS c
INNER JOIN  CUENTA AS CU ON c.CONTRATO=CU.CONTRATO
WHERE c.SITUACION NOT IN ('1','9')
AND c.tarifa='BT5A'
AND CU.MES BETWEEN '201907' AND '202007'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3
c.RUTA,c.CONTRATO,c.CODIGOANT,c.CODRUTA,c.NOMBRES,c.DIRECCION,
c.SITUACION,c.TARIFA
FROM CLIENTE AS c
INNER JOIN  CUENTA AS CU ON c.CONTRATO=CU.CONTRATO
WHERE c.SITUACION NOT IN ('1','9')
AND c.tarifa='BT5B'
AND CU.MES BETWEEN '201907' AND '202007'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3
c.RUTA,c.CONTRATO,c.CODIGOANT,c.CODRUTA,c.NOMBRES,c.DIRECCION,
c.SITUACION,c.TARIFA
FROM CLIENTE AS c
INNER JOIN  CUENTA AS CU ON c.CONTRATO=CU.CONTRATO
WHERE c.SITUACION NOT IN ('1','9')
AND c.tarifa='BT5BR'
AND CU.MES BETWEEN '201907' AND '202007'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You still haven't tagged your request with the DBMS you are using. Am I right supposing this is SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to solve you problem and simplify the query"

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT c.RUTA, c.CONTRATO, c.CODIGOANT, c.CODRUTA, c.NOMBRES, c.DIRECCION, c.SITUACION, c.TARIFA,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.tarifa ORDER BY NEWID()) as seqnum
      FROM CLIENTE c INNER JOIN
           CUENTA CU
           ON c.CONTRATO = CU.CONTRATO
      WHERE c.SITUACION NOT IN (1, 9) AND
            CU.MES BETWEEN '201907' AND '202007'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

I doubt you really need `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Also, I changed removed the single quotes from `NOT IN`.  The values look like numbers, so I assume they are numbers.  If the values really are strings, then use the single quotes.

EDIT:

Use `exists` to get avoid possible duplicates:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT c.RUTA, c.CONTRATO, c.CODIGOANT, c.CODRUTA, c.NOMBRES, c.DIRECCION, c.SITUACION, c.TARIFA,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.tarifa ORDER BY NEWID()) as seqnum
      FROM CLIENTE c
      WHERE c.SITUACION NOT IN (1, 9) AND
            EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM CUENTA CU
                    WHERE cu.CONTRATO = c.CONTRATO AND
                          CU.MES BETWEEN '201907' AND '202007'
                   )
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks by your response, I execute the code but show me three registers repeated by Rate (Tarifa) each one with a different seqnum (1-2-3).

Comment: `DISTINCT` is probably needed, because a client can have multiple cuentas, hence the separate table. The join then would make `DISTINCT` necessary, which can be avoided by using `EXISTS` or `IN` instead. Well, just guessing :-)

Comment: Hi, it's because each client has various rows by each month in the "Cuenta" Table, how I show 3 random registers by each Rate (Tarifa) and by each Month (Anomes)?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . That would mean that all the columns in the query are the same.

Comment: Yep, we select cliente rows and my guess was that by joining with cuentas we get the cliente rows multifold. Now, seeing OP's comment on my answer, I fear that the cliente table contains duplicates (multiple rows for the same client in the "client" table).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this is SQL Server:

1. Don't join. Use `IN` to get the clients where the contract matches your conditions.
2. Use `NEWID` to get random numbers.
3. Use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank your rows.
4. If you want to use `TOP`, you need `TOP WITH TIES` and an `ORDER BY` clause.

The query:

```
SELECT TOP (3) WITH TIES
  *
FROM cliente
WHERE contrato IN
(
  SELECT contrato
  FROM cuenta
  WHERE mes BETWEEN '201907' AND '202007'
)
AND situacion NOT IN (1, 9)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tarifa ORDER BY NEWID());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks by your response, I execute the code but show me three registers repeated by Rate (Tarifa), it's because each client have various rows by anomes (Month).

SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT c.RUTA, c.CONTRATO, c.CODIGOANT, c.CODRUTA, c.NOMBRES, c.DIRECCION, c.SITUACION, c.TARIFA,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.tarifa ORDER BY NEWID()) as seqnum
      FROM CLIENTE c INNER JOIN
           CUENTA CU
           ON c.CONTRATO = CU.CONTRATO
      WHERE c.SITUACION NOT IN (1, 9)
      AND CU.MES='201907' AND CU.PAGADO>0
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 3;

Comment: This is not my query, but Gondon's. Have you tried mine? (There is no join in my table, because we don't want duplicates. When you want data from a table, selewct from that table. If there are conditions use `WHERE`. Don't join, when it's only about looking up data in the other table.)

Comment: If you get the same client thrice for one tarifa with *my* query, that would indicate that while you *call* this table cliente (client), there is not exactly one row per client in the table. This would mean that despite its name it's *not* the client table, but some transaction table or whatever. I think it's time you explain the tables in your request. What do they represent? What are their unique keys?